# Near 100% accuracy during training but <50% during testing/validation on image classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I've been trying to train my model for the past few days, but each time no matter what I try, I get the same issue. My accuracy starts low and reaches above 90% within the first epoch, but validation at the end of each epoch comes out as anywhere between 20-50%, and testing the model predictions is accurate with some classes but completely wrong for most. My dataset has 20000 images, 2000 per class, and 100 testing images(can get more if necessary). I would greatly appreciate any input any of you have, as I am quite new to machine learning as a whole and I do not completely understand everything that goes into this.

I've looked at several posts and articles online describing similar issues and their fixes, whether it be defining activations as their own layers rather than parameters, adding in batch normalization layers and changing their momentums, trying several different optimizers and learning rates, different sizes of datasets, using a custom initializer, and even completely changing the structure of my model. Nothing works.

Here is the main part of the network:

```py
model = Sequential()
initializer = keras.initializers.he_normal(seed=None)

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=initializer, input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=initializer))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=initializer))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=initializer))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=initializer))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=initializer))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2048, use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=initializer))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, use_bias=False))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00005), metrics=['accuracy'])

# train the model
if not testing_mode:
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', scores[0])
print('Test accuracy:', scores[1])
```

Here is the last few batches of an epoch and its validation at the end:

```
19776/20000 [============================>.] - ETA: 25s - loss: 0.4859 - acc: 0.9707
19840/20000 [============================>.] - ETA: 18s - loss: 0.4855 - acc: 0.9708
19904/20000 [============================>.] - ETA: 11s - loss: 0.4851 - acc: 0.9709
19968/20000 [============================>.] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.4848 - acc: 0.9710 
20000/20000 [==============================] - 2323s 116ms/step - loss: 0.4848 - acc: 0.9710 - val_loss: 1.9185 - val_acc: 0.5000
```

Edit: I've been told to add more info about my dataset. I am training on [this](https://www.kaggle.com/gti-upm/leapgestrecog) dataset with 10 classes of different hand gestures. Each image is preprocessed to be 128x128 and grayscale, and my 100-image testing set is 10 images taken from every class in the training set. I know it's better to get data that's separate from the training set for testing, but I wasn't sure if deleting images from the training set was a good idea. This is also one of the reasons why I think this issue is strange, because if the model is overfitting onto the training data, then why is the accuracy so low when faced with data it has already seen? Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Your model is overfitting! You'll need to describe what you're training on, what you're testing on, the classification values, the distribution of the class values, and whole bunch more to get more meaningful comments.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your model is overfitting which means that it's adapting [learning] very closely to the training set.

This can be caused if your training set doesn't include all cases types, try shuffling your data again.

Comment: Do you know of any way to shuffle the data without messing up the labels?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your model is overfitting. This means that your model has poor prediction accuracy and cannot generalize beyond the training set. There are several reasons this could occur, so a recommendation cannot be made until we have more information about your model.

Edit 1

My understanding is that a model should not have the test set observations found in the training set. I am not very familiar with the syntax used but I think you can separate the sets using the `validation_split` parameter in the `.fit` function. A recommended split would be around 85% training / 15% test

Source: https://keras.io/models/model/

Comment: @mattsap's comment is a good start. If i understand your edit#1 correctly, is your test set included in your training set? i am not following that

Comment: The test images are stored in a separate location, but they can all be found somewhere in the training set. So, yes.

Comment: To my understanding that is not good. Test set data should NOT be in your training set.

Comment: So, should I create a new testing set but remove the images I take from the training set?

Comment: I was going to do this originally, however it seems that parameter takes the split from the end of the training set before it shuffles, and my training set is loaded in order at first. It relies on shuffling. If you know of any way I can shuffle beforehand, I will use the validation split.

Comment: what do you mean when you say in order?, I am not following this concept of order in your data set

Comment: The images for each class in the training set are stored in a folder that encompasses the entire class. When I load these images into an array, it goes folder by folder, such that (for example) the first 2000 values in the array all belong to the same class, and the next 2000 to another class, etc. So, if I did a 10% validation split, it would split one entire class of images from the rest of the dataset.

Comment: is it possible to shuffle the data set before calling .fit() then?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. I don't know of any ways to do it, and it would have to also be a way that lets me shuffle the labels in the exact same way. I'm going to look at the Keras documentation and look for one.

Comment: any progress on the model?

Answer (score 0):

As you are training your Convolutional Neural Network(CNN), to get rid of the overfitting problem, you can apply the following approaches -

1. You can play around with the **Dropout** with their probability value which acts as a 
   regularizer for CNN
2. Add more data by using techniques like **Data Augmentation**
3. Use **Transfer Learning** (Pre-Trained Models)

Comment: Should I be using higher or lower dropout values?

Comment: Good value for dropout in a hidden layer is between 0.5 and 0.8. But I can say, you can play around with values range in between 0.3 to 0.8 and check which gives the better result.